# Sails: locals from jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, momentjs

I am trying to use advantage of `moment.js` to parse dates in jade templates under sails app.
I have read that in order to use `moment.js` in views server side, I have to utilize the concept of `locals`.

Therefore according to [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/views/locals) I am modifying my route to:

```
var moment = require("moment");
...
'get /post/:post_id': {
    controller: 'PostController',
    action: 'readPostById',
    locals: { moment: moment } // adding moment.js
},
```

But when I try to use in from jade

```
...
- var date = moment().format('YYYY'); 
span= date
...
```

..I get and error saying that **moment is not a function**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `span= moment().format('YYYY');` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out by myself. The reason behind is that defining `locals` in the route is the same as passing paramaters for template upon `res.render()`. In my case I was passing paramaters/data with template and it seems that this will override what's being passed with `locals`.

So if you want to use `moment` in your template pass it over upon rendering, not with `locals`, like this:

```
var moment = require("moment");
...
showPage: function(req, res) {
    res.render('page.jade', {moment: moment, other_data: "just to test"});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign class to locals

in your code

`locals: { moment: moment }` it's exactly the same of `locals: { moment: moment.toString() }`

so the value of moment will be

```
moment = "function utils_hooks__hooks() {
        return hookCallback.apply(null, arguments);
    }"
```

the solution, you need to calculate your variables outside of view

```
locals: { currentYear: moment().format('YYYY') }
```

Comment: According to [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/views/locals) somehow I can, because sails automatically passes lodash to all views.

Comment: I think that is because lodash defined as globals
maybe you can export moment as global too

Comment: so maybe if you created service in `src/services` with moment name and return moment instance you can get it inside your views!